# MySQL Column definition for hasMany relationship in Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have an employees table defined with their alphanumeric employee_id (currently 9-characters but can increase upto 15) as the key:

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
    emp_id VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    emp_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ...
);
```

Now, I've to create a Group entity where each employee can be part of multiple groups:

```
CREATE TABLE group (
    group_id VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    group_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    employees ????, <--- how should this be defined?
    FOREIGN KEY fk_emp(employees) REFERENCES employee(emp_id)
);
```

I can create the controller and view for this using gii or manually, without an issue. The group creation/update form will have a multi-select for employees.

As an alternative, does Yii2 support sets?

Comment: What do you mean by sets? Can you clarify what is it that you're trying to find out about Yii2? :)

Comment: @mrateb I'm trying to use this as a column definition https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set.html but not sure if Yii2 has any support for SET types.

EDIT: On a second thought, that wouldn't serve the purpose. Rather a way to store a set of foreign keys in a column is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

You link the group and employee tables together via a third table.  This allows you to link employees into many groups, and groups to link to many employees as well.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to avoid creating a third table just to create the linkages. Since it is going to hold only keys, is there a way to include the contents directly as a column in one of the tables - like a set of foreign keys?

Comment: If you have only one employee per group (!), sure.  Otherwise you could create a varchar that contains the list of employee IDs in the group, separated by ','.  But then your code becomes messy, you cannot use SQL to process employees inside groups, ...  Read about normal forms of database architecture.  Your desire to avoid this scenario demonstrate a "newbie" attitude, and at my company, your whole application would be rejected and rewritten.  No offense intended, just pointing out issues with your idea.

Comment: Messy code: you need to know in which groups your employee is.  You have to loop through all the groups and see if his employee id is in the list of members.  With the third table, you have 1 sql to do and voila!

Comment: Actually, that's the exact reason I was trying to avoid extra normalization: we never need to query which groups an employee is part of. Actions will be performed on groups and trickle down to employees. Wherever, two way relationship was needed, that is already going to a third table. This is one specific case, where just having a serialized set would suffice. If it was possible, it would save us from querying three tables (group -> employees_in_group -> employee) instead of 2 (group -> employee).

Comment: Your call, but remember that requirements change, clients want more, ...

Comment: I agree. In any case, I don't seem to have an option. But, it would have been useful if such a set (0 or more) was possible as a column instead of using a separate table to maintain foreign keys. This may have many use cases.

Comment: As I said, it is possible, but you have to concatenate many values together inside on column.  How you separate each value is up to you so you have to define it in your code.  Ex. Active Directory uses such a setup.  The MemberOf field stores all groups the user belongs to.  But to accelerate searches, groups also list all users in them.  So the same info is stored twice, which can lead to all sorts of problems.