# Fetch comma separated values from mysql database particularly

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have database where i have a column where multiple ids are saved in comma separated way. That ids are defined some other table . I am fetching the but i am getting result where there is single value (no comma)

i need all all the ids value fetched there definition from another table and show.

Is it possible in mysql query ?

Comment: Your screen capture cut off the column names.

Comment: You can use MySQL subquery with IN clause.

Comment: Can you please describe how to ? @Vishal

Comment: Perhaps you can post an example of the data you're working with and what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Your query can just select the column name and you will get the complete set of values.  Than explode on ','.  But the real solution is not to do that at all and modify your database schema.  When you want to assign multiple values from one table to the next, don't list then like that, create a third table to link them together.  Look at this other question for a example of that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46889722/mysql-column-definition-for-hasmany-relationship-in-yii2/46889890#46889890

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get first all id's,by column, and then explode it by comma,

```
$explode = explode(',',$array->column);
```

then using foreach pass the value to another table to get the row,

```
 foreach($explode as $single){
  // pass single id to query using where condition you can get row of that id.
 }
```

or you can also use subquery, do google am sure stack overflow gives better result.

Comment: If it solved your issue then do not forget to mark answer as right with upvote.